# Linker error when trying to link to a dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker-errors

I have a Dll Which has 4 files Header files-1.StreamReader.h 2.StreamWriter.h Source Files-StreamReader.cpp 2.StreamWriter.cpp in windows VS2008.

*StreamReader.h*

```
Class StreamReader{

public:

static __declspec(dllexport) StreamReader* GetInstance();
//other functions

private:
  StreamReader(){}
  ~StreamReader(){}

  static StreamReader *m_pInstance;
};
```

*StreamReader.cpp*

```
StreamReader *StreamReader::m_pInstance=NULL;

StreamReader *StreamReader::GetInstance()
{
 return((m_pInstance==NULL)?m_pInstance=new StreamReader:m_PInstance);
}

//other functions
```

I have a very similar structure for StreamWriter and a GetInstance() there as well.

When I link to this dll statically in a exe it complains during compilation

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class
>   StreamReader * StreamReader::m_pInstance"
>   (?m_pInstance@StreamReader@@0PAV1@A)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: static class StreamReader * __cdecl
>   StreamReader::GetInstance(void)"
>   (?GetInstance@StreamReader@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function _main

The exe is also written in c++. But it can find StreamWriter symbol. The StreamWriter and StreamReader files are essentially the same except for the fact that one reads and one writes to a file. What am i missing? Thank you

Comment: Is the funny capitalization in `StreamREAder` a mistake in transcribing to Stack Overflow (_please_ use copy and paste!) or an error in your source?

Comment: that was a cool catch...but sadly it is just a shortcoming of my typing skill and not of my programming !

Comment: Don't type... just copy it in.

Comment: What do you mean by linking to DLL statically? Are you linking an import library? Check that symbols are exported correctly with dumpbin.

Comment: @Gene oh I meant am linking to the import library and dumpbin shows me the exact mangled name of GetInstance() method as the one displayed in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .cpp files are actually in the project and not just in the folder.  That way, the compiler knows to compile them and produce the object files that the linker is looking for.

Comment: Good point. But  yes the cpp files are indeed part of the buid

Answer (score 0):

When you import a dll you need to have dllimport declared.
You have 
    static __declspec(dllexport) StreamReader* GetInstance();
you need
    static **__declspec(dllimport)** StreamReader* GetInstance();

you can use the same header file for this by using a preprocessor definition

```
#ifdef _EXPORTING
#define CLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

static CLASS_DECLSPEC StreamReader* GetInstance();
```

make sure to add _EXPORTING preprocessor definition to the project that exports the DLL